# cocoa - can't access instance variable on button click

Tags: cocoa, variables, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting, instance

I have a method called `getProjects`. In my method I parse data from json. I save `name` and `id` of the project in my instance variable `projectsArray` which is an `NSMutableArray`.

The problem is that I have a button (`IBAction`) called `writeFile` and if I try to log the array on click, my app crashes. The error message is `ESC_BAD_ACCESS`. But why? I am using ARC.
`` `Method getProjects ``

```
- (void)getProjects {
int count = 0;
self.projectsArray      = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
SBJsonParser *parser    = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *request   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@projects.json", urlPath]]];
NSData *response        = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *json_string   = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *projects       = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *project in projects) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

    [dict setObject:[project objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [dict setObject:[project objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];

    [self.projectsArray insertObject:dict atIndex:count];
    [self.selectProject addItemWithTitle:[project objectForKey:@"name"]];
    count++;
}
```

}

And I call the method in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self getProjects];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.projectsArray);
}
```

The log in my applicationDidFinishLaunching returns my array.

Comment: "ESC_BAD_ACCES" - I don't know about such an error message. (Hint: ortography)

Comment: What class is `writeFile` in and, if it's not the app delegate, how does the object running that method get its reference to the projects array?

Comment: The property is declared as assign and writeFile is running the appDelegate. I'm sorry, i mean "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: I changed assign to retain and now it works. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you have already found the cause of the issue:

> I changed assign to retain and now it works. But why?

The reason is that by declaring the property as `assign`, when you set it, its value is not retained.

So:

1. you create the array like this:

   ```
     self.projectsArray      = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
   ```
2. `arraywithCapacity` will give you an autoreleased object;
3. the object is not retain when assigning it to the property;
4. at some point in time, *before* the NSLog is executed, the object is deallocated.
5. crash.